# how to draw the complex work flow using tikz 2.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

I wish to draw a complex work flow using tikz 2.0 because I tried to update the tikz to 2.1, there are many problems. The work work flow is described as follows:
[image]
I have tried to draw it by locating the rectangles using coordinator, however it is very hard to make it precise, is there any simpler and better way? Thanks!
the code I tried is

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw (-0.5,0)  rectangle (-3,-3);
\draw (0.5,0)   rectangle (3,-3);
\draw (-1,0)    rectangle (-2,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Disclaimer

Just after writing this whole answer, I read Alain Matthes' one and realized that the question was about tikz 2.0. I overlooked this requirement so my answer is probably not useful for the OP. But I decided to leave here anyway because it illustrates some techniques which can be useful to other readers.

## Original answer

You should use `positioning` library in order to get rid of absolute coordinates, and `fit` library to draw nodes around other nodes. Let's build your example step by step:

First, nodes a, b, c, and d can be positioned relatively each other the following way:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  my box/.style = {draw, minimum width = 3em, minimum height=1.5em},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[my box]             (a) {a};
\node[my box, below=of a] (b) {b};
\draw[->] (a) -- (b);

\node[my box, right=1cm of a] (c) {c};
\node[my box, below=of c]     (d) {d};
\draw[->] (c) -- (d);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: abcd]

Then you can use `fit` to draw the rectangles around these:

```
\node[draw, fit=(a) (b)] (ab) {};
\node[draw, fit=(c) (d)] (cd) {};
```

[image: fit]

Now, you can add the diamond and connections to `(ab)` and `(cd)`. To position the diamond properly centered, I use an auxiliar coordinate `(aux)` interpolated between `(ab)` and `(cd)`:

```
\coordinate (aux) at ($(ab.north)!.5!(cd.north)$);
\node[draw, diamond, above=of aux] (diamond) {};
\draw[->] (diamond) -| (ab);
\draw[->] (diamond) -| (cd);
```

[image: diamond]

Now, using `fit` again, we draw the box around all of this. But there is a problem, since I presume you want that box of the same size than the one which contains `e` and `f` (to be drawn later). A workaround can be to give it a `minimum height`, and use the same amount for both boxes. This minimum height is found by trial and error, and this is why I don't like very much this part...

```
\node[draw, fit=(diamond) (ab) (cd), minimum height=3.5cm] (left part) {};
```

[image: left part]

Finally, using the same techniques again, you can position nodes `e` and  `f` relative to `c`, and `fit` a box of a minimum height around them. In order to get a proper alignment of the right box with the left one, I had to insert a "invisible" diamond on top of `e`:

```
\node[my box, right=2cm of c, label=90:hl] (e) {e};
\node[my box, below=of e]     (f) {f};
\node[diamond, above=of e] (diamond aux) {};
\node[draw, fit=(diamond aux) (f), minimum height=3.5cm] (right part) {};
```

[image: left-and-right]

Finally, the last diamond is added using the same technique than for the first one:

```
\coordinate (aux) at ($(left part.south)!.5!(right part.south)$);
\node[draw, diamond, below=of aux] (cross diamond) {};
\draw (cross diamond.north) -- (cross diamond.south)
      (cross diamond.west) -- (cross diamond.east);
\draw[->, shorten >=1pt] (left part) |- (cross diamond);
\draw[->, shorten >=1pt] (right part) |- (cross diamond);
```

This completes the figure (and after it, the complete code):

[image: complete]

## The code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
my box/.style = {draw, minimum width = 3em, minimum height=1.5em},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[my box]             (a) {a};
\node[my box, below=of a] (b) {b};
\draw[->] (a) -- (b);

\node[my box, right=1cm of a] (c) {c};
\node[my box, below=of c]     (d) {d};
\draw[->] (c) -- (d);

\node[draw, fit=(a) (b)] (ab) {};
\node[draw, fit=(c) (d)] (cd) {};

\coordinate (aux) at ($(ab.north)!.5!(cd.north)$);
\node[draw, diamond, above=of aux] (diamond) {};
\draw[->] (diamond) -| (ab);
\draw[->] (diamond) -| (cd);

\node[draw, fit=(diamond) (ab) (cd), minimum height=3.5cm] (left part) {};

\node[my box, right=2cm of c, label=90:hl] (e) {e};
\node[my box, below=of e]     (f) {f};
\node[diamond, above=of e] (diamond aux) {};
\node[draw, fit=(diamond aux) (f), minimum height=3.5cm] (right part) {};

\coordinate (aux) at ($(left part.south)!.5!(right part.south)$);

\node[draw, diamond, below=of aux] (cross diamond) {};
\draw (cross diamond.north) -- (cross diamond.south)
      (cross diamond.west) -- (cross diamond.east);
\draw[->, shorten >=1pt] (left part) |- (cross diamond);
\draw[->, shorten >=1pt] (right part) |- (cross diamond);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it helps a lot, anther question, how to move the labe h1 at the top of the rectangle? it seems very near to the box

Comment: @sweetyBaby You can move the `label=90:hl` option to the node `diamond aux`, which is an invisible node at top of `e`.

Comment: @sweetyBaby or, for fine grained positioning you can remove the option `label=90:hl` and manually place the text below the top border of the rectangle, with `\node[below=2mm of right part.north] {hl};`

Comment: thanks, if I want to add label "test" besides the arrow that connects box "a" and "b", I tried "\draw[->] (a) -- (b){test};" but it doesn't work

Comment: @sweetyBaby you can only typeset text inside a `node` (or a `label`  option which is a shortcut for a node). But you can add nodes to a line. You have to specify the position inside the line (eg: `midway`) and the position of the text with respect the line (eg: `left`). In summary: `\draw[->] (a)--(b) node[midway, left] {test};`

Answer (score 7):

It's not easy to work with pgf 2.0 because I forgot a lot of things. It's possible to use the calc library with pgf 2.00 but here I used an old method to build the picture. If this code works for you, You can get a better code with some helps.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,shapes} 
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{rec}=[draw,minimum width = 1cm,minimum height=.75cm,outer sep=6pt]  
\node[rec] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[rec] (b) at ([yshift=-2cm]a) {b}; 
\node[rec] (c) at ([xshift=3cm]a) {c};
\node[rec] (d) at ([yshift=-2cm]c) {d};
\coordinate (x) at ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=+0.25cm] a.north west);
\coordinate (y) at ([xshift=+0.25cm,yshift=-0.25cm] b.south east);
\coordinate (u) at ([xshift=-0.25cm,yshift=+0.25cm] c.north west);
\coordinate (v) at ([xshift=+0.25cm,yshift=-0.25cm] d.south east);

\coordinate (xx) at ([xshift=-1.25cm,yshift=+2.25cm] a.north west);
\coordinate (yy) at ([xshift=+1.25cm,yshift=-1.25cm] d.south east);
\node [draw,fit=(x)(y)] (rec1){};
\node [draw,fit=(u)(v)] (rec2){};

\node [draw,fit=(xx)(yy)] (rec3){};
\draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\draw[->] (c) -- (d);

\path (rec1.north) -- (rec2.north) node[shape=diamond,minimum size=.75cm,pos=.5,yshift=1cm,draw](dia)  {} ;
\draw[<-] (rec1) |- (dia);
\draw[<-] (rec2) |- (dia);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]